Play the same audio file over two bluetooth speakers at the same time using Raspberry Pi 4
I need to play the same .mp3 file (happy to convert if need be) over at least two Bluetooth speakers at the same time. With the speakers I have and my phone I run into now issues - so not a speaker problem.
Thus far I have been able to connect to both speakers but when trying to play audio the audio being played seems to jump between the two speakers or seems to play solely on one speaker.

this is not a Raspberry Pi specific question ... it is either a Linux question or a computer hardware question  ... please do research in the Linux realm or in the computer hardware realm
